# How to write to Powershell collection

Tags: arrays, powershell, collections

I want to add output from below command to some sort of array or collection:

`Get-MpThreatDetection  | Where-Object {$_.InitialDetectionTime -ge $time}`

It could produce output of multiple detections. As per screenshot below e.g. EVENT1 (fields from ActionSuccess till PSComputerName) and same fields for EVENT2 and so on (in case of multiple detections).

I would like to write all values of all fields for each EVENT to some sort of array or collection so later I can get value of each field something like below:

`$Result = $event1.actionsuccess`

`$Threat = $event2.ThreatID`

[image: Command output]

How I can write this to some sort of array or collection and later to get required value of required field for specific EVENT number?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is a Hashtable. Hashtables work on a `Key = Value` basis, so you would choose or generate a key that you can reference later to retrieve the desired value. For example, let us say that you have Event1 saved in `$Event1` and Event2 saved in `$Event2`. You could then form a hashtable like this:

```
$Events = @{
    'Event1' = $Event1
    'Event2' = $Event2
}
```

Then later you can recall a specific event by referencing the key like this:

```
$Events['Event1']
```

Or, to just get the `ThreatID` of Event2 you could do this:

```
$Events['Event2'].ThreatID
```

The keys can be anything, but remember that you need to have some way to reference that thing, so often times strings are the easiest way to do it.

**Edit:** In response to how you would add the same keys from multiple events to the same hashtable, the answer is you wouldn't. The point is to have a unique identifier for the key, and the entire event as the value. There's a couple ways to do that. The first way is to determine a unique value that each event has (in this example I will use `DetectionID` which is a unique identifier for each threat detection as noted [here](https://powershell.one/wmi/root/microsoft/windows/defender/msft_mpthreatdetection)). You could do:

```
# Create empty hashtable
$Events =@{}
# Iterate through results, and add each event to the hashtable by DetectionID
Get-MpThreatDetection  | Where-Object {$_.InitialDetectionTime -ge $time} | ForEach-Object{
    $Events.Add($_.DetectionID, $_)
}
```

Then later you can reference any event by the DetectionID. Like this:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> $Events['009c9051-71cc-479f-ae8f-1bff94ad1e3b'].ThreatID

2147593794
```

Alternatively you could just capture all events in a simple array, and then reference events by their index. That would look more like this:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> $Events = Get-MpThreatDetection  | Where-Object {$_.InitialDetectionTime -ge $time}

PS C:\Windows\System32> $Events[0].initialdetectiontime

23/08/2023 21:31:04

PS C:\Windows\System32> $Events[1].Resources

file:_D:\KeyGen\keygen.exe
```

Comment: This command {Get-MpThreatDetection | Where-Object {$_.InitialDetectionTime -ge $time}} can get multiple detections. So Event1 will have key from "ActionSuccess" till "PSComputername", same keys will be for Event2 and so on for others detections. Assume I can't add all detections to the single $Events hastables because of identical keys' names? Shall I create separate hashtable per each detection, e.g. $Event1 / $Event2 and so on? How I can split from single list all detections to separate $Event hashtable?

Comment: Putting all detections to simple $Events array is what I was looking for. Actually it was already applied in my scripts I didn't realized that all events can be addressed by Index e.g. Events[0] , Events[1] etc. Thank you for your help